# Trace what user has click in certain page

Tags: c#, asp.net, log4net, trace, user-activity

just a very simple question. I want to monitor user activity in my web app.Is that any way to trace what user has been click in certain webpage?For example user click button1 in default1.aspx . A log file will be create and log that user has been create button1 in default.aspx

Is it possible to make it?

Answer (score 1):

Try [this library (JAVASCRIPT CLICK TRACKING LIBRARY
By Erik Vold )](https://github.com/erikvold/click-tracking-js-lib) and also read [this blog](http://www.ravelrumba.com/blog/tracking-links-with-javascript/) for more information

Answer (score 0):

You could create a simple web service and post data about how the user interacts with your application by making ajax calls to the web service.

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) would help you "listen" to all buttons on your page and make ajax calls.